Quantifying the causal effect of change in variability
Say there is a wood cutting machine. When we tune the machine the accuracy of the machine increases. Meaning the machine is supposed to cut $\mu$ inch blocks but has error $\epsilon$. The variability in the error decreases when tuning.
I would like to understand the causal effect of tuning the machine.
Utilizing Rubin causal model we can specify potential outcomes of the observed inches of the block and create a contrast.
$$
Y(0) = \mu + \epsilon(0) 
$$
$$
Y(1) = \mu + \epsilon(1) 
$$
The difference in the potential errors is the causal effect of the tuning for a particular block.
$$
Y(1) - Y(0) =  \epsilon(1) - \epsilon(0)
$$
Say that errors are distributed the following
$$
\epsilon(1) \sim N(0, \sigma_t^2)  
$$
$$
\epsilon(0) \sim N(0, \sigma_c^2)
$$
Now we don't observe the individual potential outcome, so we take the expectation:
$$
{\bf E}[\epsilon(1)] - {\bf E}[\epsilon(0)] = 0
$$
The expectation is zero which indicates no causal effect which is not indicative of the change in variability. How would I go about setting up this problem in the potential outcome framework?

You may want to edit your post to avoid spelling *causal" as casual? (spellcheck will not catch this...)

What exactly is your estimand?  As you've noted, the average treatment effect is 0 since the change does not change the mean of the potential outcomes, only their variance.

What would be a relevant estimand that captures the change in variance?
